# Incorrect syntax near SET in SQL Server 2000 stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

I generated a SQL script from SQL Server 2000 because I can't just use the `.bak` file to restore into version 2014. When I tried to execute the generated SQL script on the new SQL Server 2014, I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'

Checking the blamed line:

```
IF ISNULL(@pi_strMChargeNo,'') = '' BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TPURCHASEGROUP(MCHARGENO, CASHPRICE, COUPONPRICE, EVENTPRICE, TOTALPRICE, PITEMCNT, REGDATE, UPDDATE)
    VALUES(@v_strMChargeNo, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, GETDATE(), GETDATE())

    IF @@ERROR <> 0 
    BEGIN
        SET @po_strErrMsg = 'TPURCHASEGROUP INSERT FAIL'
        SET @po_intRetVal = 2266
        SET RETURN -- blamed
    END
END
```

Might be changes to the syntax from 2000 to 2014, but what? Or possibly just delete the line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without further context, it looks like you should replace the line `SET RETURN` by `RETURN`.

Regarding your problem with restoring a backup. You might want to try restoring on SQL Server 2008, increase the compatibility level of the database to `100`, make a new backup and restore that under SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Nice tip :) Will try. Though I still would like to have a SQL script. I'll try to replace `SET RETURN` with `RETURN`.

Comment: yup, replacing those with just `RETURN` fixed the problem. Though a few others come up. But not related to this topic anymore. Accepted.